# Pdfjs PDFViewer not render all pages in dom

Tags: pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am using the PDFViewer from `pdfjs-dist` in react app to render the pdf. Pdf is getting render and I can see all pages in DOM but some pages are loaded as we scroll down page is set with  data-loaded="true".

How can we load all pages without loader and data-loaded="true"?

[image]